# Masking text / replacing a region with one character

Tags: text-editing, replace

I often find I want to "mask" text in a text file, such as overwriting a secret value in an example file.

For example, I want to change
`SECRET_PASSWORD=123abc456`
to
`SECRET_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXX`.

I can't find any way to do this very easily in Emacs.

I've tried writing a function to do this, where a marked region gets replaced with a character interactively:

```
(defun mask-text (start end)
  "Overwrite a selected region with the selected mask character"
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((region-length (- end start))
        (mask-char (read-char "Enter mask character")))
    (forward-char (- region-length))
    (delete-char region-length)
    (insert-char mask-char region-length)))
```

This kind of works, but fails if the mark is earlier in the text than the start of the marked region. I could hack the function around to make it more complicated, but I wondered if there was a nicer way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother to write a function for this: I'd just use [`replace-regexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html#index-back-reference_002c-in-regexp-replacement) to replace any character (except newlines) with `X` or whatever. Select the region to mask, then

```
M-x replace-regexp RET . RET X RET
```

or

```
C-M-% . RET X RET !
```

If you do want to make a Lisp function, you can make a trivial wrapper around `replace-regexp`. [The documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search-and-Replace.html) discourages this, because it's somewhat slow and it changes the point and the mark data, but that's not really a concern in this particular case. Still, your approach is cleaner (doesn't refresh unduly, doesn't change the match data, ...). It could just use a few tweaks:

- Obtain the replacement character through an `interactive` form.
- Error out early if the buffer is read-only.
- Apply to the clicked window if bound to a mouse event.
- Don't make an assumption of where the point is originally: start at `start`. And since you're just going to delete something there, you might as well call `delete-region` directly.
- As an improvement, leave the point on the same side of the region. (Or more generally, if called from Lisp and the point is neither `start` nor `end`, leave the point wherever it was, even in the middle of the replaced region.)

```el
(defun mask-text (start end mask-char)
  "Overwrite the region with the selected mask character."
  (interactive "@*r\ncMasking character: ")
  (let ((region-length (- end start))
    (original-point (point)))
    (delete-region start end)
    (goto-char start)
    (insert-char mask-char region-length)
    (goto-char original-point)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Learned some stuff - I don't usually use `replace-regexp` but I probably should get more used to it. I didn't realise `interactive` could do more stuff. Your version definitely an improvement, especially using `delete-region`. Would using `save-excursion` make sense here?

Comment: OK - never mind, tried `save-excursion`, and it doesn't work here.

Comment: @RichSmith `save-excursion` is the normal way to preserve the cursor position around a block of code that moves around. It preserves the “logical” position of the cursor: for example, if the point was originally at position 100 and you run `(save-excursion (goto-char 1) (delete-char))`, the point will end up at position 99 since one character was deleted before it. *(cont.)*

Comment: *(cont.)* This is a rare exception where `save-excursion` would be suboptimal: if the point was in the middle of the deleted-and-reinserted region, `save-excursion` would just move it to the end of the region, since it doesn't know that we want a 1:1 correspondence between deleted and inserted characters. Because of this 1:1 correspondence, restoring the numerical value of the point is the right thing.

Comment: Thanks! (btw: you need a newline in that triple backtick block or the function definition gets swallowed; SE won't let me suggest an edit of less than 6 chars!)